# a "piece" vs. an "item" of clothing

Tags: meaning, differences, uncountable-nouns

What is the difference between an *item* of clothing and a *piece* of clothing? Can I say "three pieces of clothing" or "three items of clothing"? Are they used identically?

Comment: They mean the same thing. In American English, "*item of clothing*" sounds very stuffy and formal, and would not be used in colloquial speech. It might be used on invoices. For questions like these on the basics of English, I recommend you ask on [ELL.se].

Comment: There are 2 questions hiding here: one (in the title and the tag) is about **Uncountable nouns**, while the other (in the main body) is about **Difference between items & pieces**. I have answer both below.

Comment: With @Hellion changing the question , my comments and my answer do not make sense. I will have to delete my answer.

Comment: @Prem it's clear that the OP knows that *clothing* is normally a mass/uncountable noun, otherwise the sentences would have been: "Three clothings". The OP is asking about the difference in meaning and usage  between *item* and *piece*. *That* is the real question. :) However, you can modify your answer, you can leave it as it is, for the benefit of future visitors, or you can keep it deleted. There's nothing "wrong" in fine-tuning an answer.

Comment: You might also consider articles of clothing, or simply garments.

Comment: @Mari-LouA , thanks for the clarification. I am not sure if OP is fully aware of the countability of "clothing" and "item of clothing" , because the original title was **"a piece of clothing uncountable noun"** which I read as **"Is a piece of clothing an uncountable noun ?"** and I answered that with "no , it is countable". Then the body asks another question , which I answered too. Now , with title change , OP might still not be sure of the countability , but the current question is answered by other folks. Hence I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference; "piece" and "item" are merely different counters used with clothing. Note that "article" is also used.

So the statements

> . . . three pieces of clothing
>   . . . three items of clothing
>   . . . three articles of clothing

are functionally the same.

Comment: There are 2 questions hiding here: one (in the title and the tag) is about **Uncountable Nouns**, while the other (in the main body) is about **Difference between Items & Pieces** . . . {{ Recommenting here, in case you did not get notifications about my earlier comment }}

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation... Usually, they are interchangeable, but there are cases where this is not so. If, for example, you were talking about a murder:

"These blood-soaked *items* of clothing...", would refer to complete garments - while "These blood-soaked *pieces* of clothing..." would be parts of a garment that were ripped or cut off.